# android app to build dynamic user input forms with sms delivery

Tags: android, sms

I am new to Android programming . I have just gone through the basic tutorials present in the samples folder when i downloaded the sdk

My task is to now build an app that does the following :

1. Create a form with 3 fields
   namely name , address and phone
   number
2. Values of these fields will be
   present in local mysql  lite
   database of android and will be
   displayed as a drop down list when i
   click the respective fields
3. after doing so , when i click the
   submit button , the app should send
   an sms to a particular contact ,
   here again the list of contacts must
   be  displayed as per what i have
   provided in the mysql lite database
   as a drop down list giving me the
   option to send a to a particular
   contact

I would appreciate any suggestions for the same

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start off just making an activity which takes text input from the user, then puts that into a sms and sends it. You can find a tutorial for sending sms [here.](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)

Once you have that working i would suggest that you then change it from text imput to your drop down menus(spinner widget) from your SQLite database, you can find a tutorial for spinners [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html), but rather than using a xml list to populate the spinner (as done in the tutorial) you would get your data from SQLite and put that into an array to use in your spinner.

Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: I am finding it difficult in getting data from SQLite ..can u suggest some ways by which it would be easier ?

Comment: Do you want an alternative to using a database or suggestions on how to get the data? How much data do you have?

Comment: I want suggestions on how to get the data.. I have a database of round about 70 entries/records approx